# javascript hide/show div's accordion with two buttons ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have several div's I want to hide a div on a button click and show on second button click. I would have used the .vissible fonction but the div's are generated in the backend so from what I understand I need to use javascript to solve the problem.

Here is my backend code.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl divTest = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            divTest.Attributes.Add("class", "divClass");
            divTest.InnerText = "Div" + i;
            form1.Controls.Add(divTest);

            ImageButton collapseButton = new ImageButton();
            collapseButton.ImageUrl = "~/images/minus.png";
            collapseButton.Height = 20;
            collapseButton.Width = 20;
            divTest.Controls.Add(collapseButton);

            ImageButton expandButton = new ImageButton();
            expandButton.ImageUrl = "~/images/plus.png";
            expandButton.Height = 20;
            expandButton.Width = 20;
            form1.Controls.Add(expandButton);


        }
```

And here is my front end code.

But the javascript dosen't produce the result I would like.

```
 <style>
.divClass {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


.collapseButton {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

<script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("divClass");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>


<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help to fix the javascript code would be greatly appreciated.  Here is what it looks like visually. When the button minus is pressed I want the div that contain the minus too be hidden. The plus shows the div that was hidden.

[image: What the divs look like]

Comment: Have you tried to use the browser javascript debugger to see what happens when you click the button? It looks like your script adds `click` events to the `div`, not to the buttons?

Comment: No, I haven't used a JavaScript debugger. Is there one in visual Studio? Do you recommend one?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you ask, you can use Chrome Developer Tools. 
To be sure your code will stop where you want to start debugging, use the command
```js
debugger;
``` 
So, in your case

```js
acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    debugger; //this will wait for you to step in
    this.classList.toggle("active");
   /*whatever your code is*/
  });
```

More info => 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-javascript-in-google-chrome-and-visual-studio-code#toc-debugging-in-google-chrome

Comment: Pressing `F12` in either IE or Chrome should open developer tools and let you use the debugger, among other things, including examining the page elements to see which have the click events and what they are set to, after the javascript runs.